# AngularJS / Firebase Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to convert an app that used a PHP API to load data into an AngularJS app to one that uses Firebase for the backend.

I think I almost got it but it is throwing an error of

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

This is where i am using 'toLowerCase'

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){

    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(i){
            if(i.english.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(i);
            }
            if(i.spain.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(i);
            }
            if(i.germany.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(i);
            }
            if(i.france.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(i);
            }
            if(i.philippines.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(i);
            }
            });
        return result;
    };

});
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `toLowerCase` method on a property of `i` which does not exist.  Assuming `i` usually containts those values, but sometimes is missing a few of them, you can fix it by changing every

```
if(i.whatever.toLowerCase()
```

to

```
if(i.whatever && i.whatever.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: In the previous version with the PHP backend it was working with, it seems like items got turned into i in firebase.


`angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
   if(item.english.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
    result.push(item);
   } `

I am very new to this whole angular/firebase concept and i doing this all wrong?

Comment: here is a link to what my data set looks like in firebase 

http://imgur.com/VgLM9ox

Comment: Not sure as I haven't used firebase, but what happens if you `console.log(i)`?  Do you see the data you expect?  What happens if outside the `foreach` you `console.log(arr)`?